# How to apply custom kernels to cuda_GpuMat in python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with opencv and cuda for a school project. The basic idea is that I want to apply a stronger blur as the video progresses. I managed to create the program for the CPU (so basically no integration with cuda) with ease.

Here is a snippet for the gpu code:

```
#before iterating over each frame of the video, i define my mat
gpu_mat = cv2.cuda_GpuMat(size, cv2.CV_32FC1)

#iterate over each frame and read the current frame
_, frame = video.read()
blur_frame(frame)

#here is my blur_frame function def
def blur_frame(gpu_mat, frame):
    #upload the frame to the gpu_mat
    gpu_mat.upload(frame)
    
    #create the 5x5 blur kernel
    np_array = np.array([[1/5 for _ in range(0, 5)] for _ in range(0, 5)], dtype = np.float32)
    umat = cv2.UMat(np_array)

    #apply the blur
    blur_filter = cv2.cuda.createLinearFilter(cv2.CV_32FC1, cv2.CV_32FC1, umat)
    blur_filter.apply(gpu_mat) #on this line i receive the following error: "(-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == type_"
```

But as you can see, I receive an error `(-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == type_` when calling `apply` function on `blur_frame`.

How can I apply custom kernels on my cuda_GpuMat correctly?

Comment: Did you have a question to ask?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my post.

Comment: The frame you read from video has probably CV_8UC3 type, then you are trying to put it to gpu_Mat of type CV_32FC1. So convert frame to CV_32FC1 before uploading.

Answer (score 0):

The frame you read from video has probably CV_8UC3 type, then you are trying to put it to gpu_Mat of type CV_32FC1. You need type conversion:

```
_, frame = video.read()
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.BGR2GRAY)

blur_frame(frame.astype(np.float32))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the tour, and [How do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)?